# OpenGL, почему не рисуется квадрат?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

const GLint WIDTH = 1280, HEIGTH = 720;

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";



const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main () \n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}";



int main() {

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGTH, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);
    if (nullptr == window) {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    GLfloat vertices[]{
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: В [мануале](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/) нет про `GL_QUADS`. Попробуйте какой-нибудь `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.

Comment: а что в этом opengl уже quads отменили, рисование одними треугольниками?

Comment: Видимо да (плюс точки и линии). В манауле к GL 2 `GL_QUADS` есть, а к GL 4 - нет. Где-то между этими версиями выпилили.